# Eventlistener for touch devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, user-agent

I'm trying to figure out if the user agent is a touch device, and if it is I want to load the addEventListener...

```
if( (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)) {
    document.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {},false);
})
```

Also, how can I detect Android devices and possibly other touch devices?

Comment: Here's answer.. if(window.Touch) { /* JavaScript for your touch interface */ }

Comment: Browser sniffing is bad, never use it, there is always an alternative. There a many, many touch devices that aren't iPhones or iPads, and Android runs on a very wide variety of devices that may or may not support touch events. And then there's Windows Mobile (or whatever it's called lately).

Comment: Don't forget `MSPointer` events.

Answer (score 0):

A simple script I used some time ago to test for touch event is:

```
var hasTouch = (function(){
  if (document && document.createEvent) {
    try {
      document.createEvent('GestureEvent');
      document.createEvent('TouchEvent');
      return true;
    } catch (e) {
      return false;
    }
  }
})();
```

I haven't used it for some time so there might be better ways, but the above still works.

You can also try Kangax's article on [Detecting event support without browser sniffing](http://perfectionkills.com/detecting-event-support-without-browser-sniffing/), which might go something like:

```
  function isTouchEventSupported(eventName) {
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    eventName = 'on' + eventName;
    var isSupported = (eventName in el);

    if (!isSupported) {
      el.setAttribute(eventName, 'return;');
      isSupported = typeof el[eventName] == 'function';
    }
    el = null;
    return isSupported;
  }

  alert(isTouchEventSupported('touchstart'));  // false in IE 8
```

Answer (score 0):

http://modernizr.github.com/Modernizr/touch.html

This is how the browser capability library modernizr does it. Why not use them?